# sugarcrm subpanel modification code

Tags: sugarcrm

I need to put some custom checking for creation and editing of opportunities in Subpanel of Accounts module. I need to check whether the last modified date is within last 5 days or not and then disable create and edit buttons for link opportunities.

I'm attaching a screenshot for better understanding.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?f02b528845.png

In which file shall I need to implement my code? Or do I need to create some custom files? I'm waiting for any kind of suggestion or help from all

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is of help...

In your subpanel definition add:

```
'fill_in_additional_fields' => true,
```

This will guarantee that the custom hook event "process_record" is fired in case the subpanel is generated.

After that create a logic hook for module Opportunities that handles this event. In the handler code add something like this:

```
// this hook is fired on several occasions (DetailView, ListView, Subpanel)
// define your conditions where you want to manipulate your field
if ($_REQUEST['...'] == 'DetailView' && $_REQUEST['module'] == '....')
   return;

if($opportunity->date_modified) ...add your code here
```

Credits go here http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/showthread.php?t=44241